# $past with an input signal

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, questasim, system-verilog-assertions

I want to verify that if an event occurrs, then at “num_ticks” in the past, some signal should have been asserted.

As an example, the property I wrote is:

```
property test_past;
  @(posedge clk)
    $rose(gnt) |-> $past(req, num_ticks);
endproperty
```

The problem here is with `num_ticks`. If `num_ticks` is an input signal to the module in which the property is written, then the assertion fails. If I declare `num_ticks` as an int, and assign it to a constant, it passes.

Does $past only work for constant values? This is not mentioned in the LRM.

I am using Questasim 10.3

Comment: I just noticed I was using an outdated version of the LRM - 2002 Accellera extensions version. Any suggestions on how to achieve $past functionality with variable num_ticks?

Comment: I used some logic around this to figure it out. Not pretty, but does the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use multiple assertions for this purpose.

Suppose num_ticks is 4 bits wide, then you can do like this.

```
genvar x;
generate
  for (x=0; x<16; x++)
  begin
    property test_past;
      @(posedge clk)
      (num_ticks == x) && $rose(gnt) |-> $past(req, x);
    endproperty
  end
endgenerate
```